# Calculator for test scores javascript

Tags: javascript, html, math

I'd like to create an average calculator for test scores. Have the user enter numbers. They can enter as many as they want. Once they enter “-1”, end the program. Display the lowest test score, the highest test score, the sum of all test scores, and the average of all test scores.

The following is my code. I've already figured out how to do the sum of the scores. However, I don't know how I can turn ALL my inputs into a string - possibly output the lowest (`Math.min`), highest (`Math.max`) and average of the test score.

I tried joining strings together but in the end I couldn't figure out how to work!

```
while (true) {
    var itemGrade = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a grade!\n\n(enter -1 to quit)"));
    var item = itemGrade + ", "
    total += itemGrade;
    if (itemGrade == -1) {
        break;
    }
}

document.write("Total: " + total)
```

Comment: create an empty Array before the while loop. push values to the array in the while loop. the rest is simple Maths after the while loop

Comment: How can I "push values to the array in the while loop"? I am kinda of a newbie!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push or https://javascript.info/array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short piece of code that should do the job. The syntax `${variable}` with ` allows variables to become strings. Total score is how you've written it. Lowest and highest simply checks if the new score entered is a higher or lower number and replaces the variable as the new lowest/highest. A count is added to calculate the average of all scores.

```
var total_score = 0.0;
var average_score = 0.0;
var lowest_score = Infinity;
var highest_score = 0.0;

var count = 0.0;
while (true) {
  var itemGrade = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a grade!\n\n(enter -1 to quit)"));
  if (itemGrade == -1) {
    break;
  }
  
  total_score += itemGrade;
  if (lowest_score > itemGrade){
    lowest_score = itemGrade;
  }
  if (highest_score < itemGrade){
    highest_score = itemGrade;
  }

  count++;
}

average_score = total_score/count;
document.write("Total Score: " + `${total_score}`);
document.write("Average Score: " + `${average_score}`);
document.write("Lowest Score: " + `${lowest_score}`);
document.write("Highest Score: " + `${highest_score}`);
```

Comment: The `lowest_score` always shows 0 no matter what I enter. Could you please check? Other than that, everything works fine

Comment: Changing the defined lowest_score to infinity did the trick. That was happening because the lowest score was already set to a low of 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
var item = []
item.push(itemGrade)
```

You can create an empty array and use push() inside the while loop to add value to end of an array or use unshift() in case you want to add in starting position of the array

Comment: Your answer is helpful as well! Thanks @akitirk!